# OpenCV Python: How to overlay an image into the centre of another image

Tags: python, opencv

How can I paste a smaller image into the center of another image? Both images have the same height, but the smaller one has a width that is always smaller.

The resulting image should be the smaller image with black bars around it so it is square.

```
resizedImg = cv2.resize(img, (newW, 40))
blankImg = np.zeros((40, 40, 1), np.uint8)
```

**resizedImg**

[image: resizedImg]

**blankImg**

[image: blankImg]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way. You compute the offsets in x and y for the top left corner of the resized image where it would be when the resized image is centered in the background image. Then use numpy indexing to place the resized image in the center of the background.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# load resized image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('resized.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = img.shape
print(h,w)

# load background image as grayscale
back = cv2.imread('background.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
hh, ww = back.shape
print(hh,ww)

# compute xoff and yoff for placement of upper left corner of resized image   
yoff = round((hh-h)/2)
xoff = round((ww-w)/2)
print(yoff,xoff)

# use numpy indexing to place the resized image in the center of background image
result = back.copy()
result[yoff:yoff+h, xoff:xoff+w] = img

# view result
cv2.imshow('CENTERED', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save resulting centered image
cv2.imwrite('resized_centered.png', result)
```

Comment: but it always saves in grey image and i want RGB output.

Comment: Then do not convert the images to grayscale. Keep them 3-channel RGB. Remove `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` from the cv2.imread() commands

Comment: yes i removed cv2.imread_grayscale but still the output is not in RGB, i was testing in jupyter notebook. i removed grayscale for both the input and bg image.

Comment: Did you remove it from both?  Are you reading the two images from disk or getting them from other processing?  If the latter, then convert any grayscale images to 3-channel using cv2.merge() or cv2.cvtColor()

Comment: yeah im reading the images from disk..i will check that code and update again thankyou.

Comment: When you say the output is always gray, do you mean it looks gray or it is single channel. An RGB image can be gray with 3 equal channels. Please post an example input, background and output showing your issue.

Comment: I was using this pic https://www.google.com/search?q=person+full+hd&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjf_-z_6p7wAhXbdH0KHaLeACIQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=person+full+hd&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIGCAAQCBAeUJVrWJVrYLNtaABwAHgAgAFOiAFOkgEBMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=ljqIYN_cH9vp9QOivYOQAg&bih=1007&biw=1920#imgrc=tY1g2ktIDqSRuM

its pure RGB but as soon as it passess through your code it gives only grey image even after removing cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE from both input and bg side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231664/discussion-between-epic-gamers-and-fmw42).

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
back = cv2.imread('back.png')
overlay = cv2.imread('overlay.png')
h, w = back.shape[:2]
print(h, w)
h1, w1 = overlay.shape[:2]
print(h1, w1)
# let store center coordinate as cx,cy
cx, cy = (h - h1) // 2, (w - w1) // 2
# use numpy indexing to place the resized image in the center of 
# background image

back[cy:cy + h1, cx:cx + w1] = overlay

# view result
cv2.imshow('back with overlay', back)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

watch this [video](https://youtu.be/Z83H2CBavRU) to learn more about overlays

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).